# custom rss templete

Tags: functions, rss, feed

The objective is to  fetch fields associated with a specific post id to create a custom rss feed.

It is required to use functions like `the_content_feed('rss2')` , `the_excerpt_rss()`  etc outside the loop to fill the rss template.

How to accomplish this (use such functions outside the loop)?

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own custom rss template and create thr loop inside it so you will have easy access to loop only function

take a look at this answer that shows how to create your custom rss [How to create additional full text RSS feeds](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22849/how-to-create-additional-full-text-rss-feeds/22863#22863)