# Creating an RSS feed with all of the prior month's posts

Tags: rss

How can I create an RSS feed that will display all posts from the prior month. So on any day in December, the feed will show all posts from November and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [**`this answer`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22849/how-to-create-additional-full-text-rss-feeds/22863#22863) to a similar question which shows a template to create your custom feed and all you need to do is add `query_posts(array('monthnum' => (int)date("m") ));` before the loop.