# Conditional tag to show content in custom rss feed?

Tags: feed, conditional-tags

[The wonderful answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22863/10691) helped me create a custom RSS feed, and that's one major part done.

I know that there's the **[`is_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed)** conditional tag to show content only if it's a feed. But is there a conditional tag to show content only in my custom feed? If not, is there any other way to do it? (**PS:** I want to change the output of Wordpress' built-in gallery in my custom feed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that was quite easy. So, if your custom feed URL (non-pretty) is `http://example.com/?feed=wpse63760_custom_feed`, then the conditional tag would be used as such:

```
if ( is_feed( $feeds = 'wpse63760_custom_feed' ) ) {
   // So what's the conditional content?
} else {
   // This is shown everywhere else
}
```